# Installing new software on Eclipse-Indigo

Tags: eclipse, software-update

When trying to install new software using Eclipse Indigo, i get

[image]

The log file says:

> Could not locate the running profile instance. The
>   eclipse.p2.data.area and eclipse.p2.profile properties may not be set
>   correctly in this application's config.ini file.

Regardless, here it is

```
org.eclipse.update.reconcile=false
eclipse.p2.profile=epp.package.jee
osgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/Documents/workspace
osgi.framework=file\:plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.7.2.v20120110-1415.jar
equinox.use.ds=true
eclipse.buildId=M20120208-0800
osgi.bundles=reference\:file\:org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.0.200.v20110815-1438.jar@1\:start
org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator.configUrl=file\:org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator/bundles.info
eclipse.product=org.eclipse.platform.ide
osgi.splashPath=platform\:/base/plugins/org.eclipse.platform
osgi.framework.extensions=reference\:file\:javax.transaction_1.1.1.v201105210645.jar
eclipse.application=org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench
eclipse.p2.data.area=@config.dir/../p2
osgi.bundles.defaultStartLevel=4
```

What am i missing please?

**eclipse.p2.data.area appears to be defined**

```
eclipse.p2.data.area=@config.dir/../p2
```

**eclipse.p2.profile appears to be defined**

```
eclipse.p2.profile=epp.package.jee
```

This is a brand new installation. No manual changes were done to  any of the above. Why is this error happening please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that Unarchiver has a bug. Untar bundle manually and everything works like a charm:

```
tar -xvf eclipse-jee-indigo-SR2-macosx-cocoa-x86_64.tar
```